# Not able to reinstall mysql

Tags: dpkg, mysql

Not able to install mysql when I run the following command:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
```

The error is:

`Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /etc/mysql/my.cnf is already managed by my.cnf.bak
dpkg: error processing package mysql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: try with `dpkg -l | grep mysql` and then remove the packages listed in the earlier command by executing `apt-get --purge autoremove`.

Comment: yep. although didnt try with autoremove. still right now the output shows nothing.
    ➜  ~ sudo dpkg -l | grep mysql
    ➜  ~

Comment: Is there any `my.cnf.bak` file somewhere in `/var/lib/mysql`?

Answer (score 2):

ok so!

I spent the last couple of days trying different things and this seems to have worked for me. Indeed the phrase `update-alternatives: error: alternative link /etc/mysql/my.cnf is already managed by my.cnf.bak` pointed me in the right direction.
Please note that I am running debian on a chromebook through crouton. This might mean there is at least one nesting linux installation which might make things different on your end. This was just what worked for me.

I had already purged every mysql file through apt-get several times, removed files one by one and even dpkg removed them, but the error kept ocurring. Finally searched for my.cnf.bak

```
`find / my.cnf.bak | grep my.cnf.bak`
```

and found it in `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives`. All of this time I had been searching in `/etc/alternatives`. In any case I finally removed this file and reinstalled mysql-server. All is well now.

Answer (score 0):

First get rid of all the MySQL files:
`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql`

Then try to install again:
`sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client`

If this fails, you could also first reconfigure it. First, find the type version of MySQL: 
`apt search mysql-server`

Then reconfigure (change the version):
`dpkg-reconfigure --force mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7`

Comment: Nope didnt work. :(. I think the main issue is `update-alternatives: error: alternative link /etc/mysql/my.cnf is already managed by my.cnf.bak` . how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

look for a file my.cnf.bak

```
find / -name "my.cnf.bak"
```

rename it to my.cnf or delete it (whether you want to use it or not)

then

```
apt-get purge mysql*
apt-get install mysql-server
```

for me it solved the problem!